# How to save / update multiple documents in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am reading all documents of a specific schema from Mongoose. Now in my program I am doing some modifications to the results I got from Mongoose over time. Something like this:

```
var model = mongoose.model("Doc", docSchema);
model.find(function(err, result){
     // for each result do some modifications
});
```

How can I send all the results back to the database to be saved? Currently I am iterating the documents and doing a save() on every document. I think there must be a better way. But currently I only find information on updating documents IN the database without returning them. Or bulk updates which do the SAME to update to each document.

Answer (score 0):

You can use update query with multi:true which update all documents in your db.
please find below reference code,

```
 model.update({ "_id": id }, { $set: { "Key": "Value" } }, { multi: true }, function (err, records) {
      if (err || !records) {
        return res.json({ status: 500, message: "Unable to update documents." });
      } else {
        return res.json({ status: 200, message: "success" });
      }
    });
```

Comment: Thnaks but that is not what i am looking for, please read the question carefully. I have multiple documents that i made individual changes to. (i.e. i am changing different properties on each document) and i want these changes to be reflected in the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make the same change to each document in the results, you could do something like this:

```
model.update({ _id: { $in: results.map(doc=>doc._id) }}, { yourField: 'new value' }, { multi: true })
```